# New node of content type always as new book

Tags: 9, nodes

I have two content types: *my-book* and *my-page*.

Is it possible to automatically create a new book (using the Book module) when a *my-book* node is created?

I was looking into using `hook_node_presave()`, but this doesn't give a node ID to use. Using `hook_entity_insert()` doesn't permit to change the field values for the newly created node.

Comment: I don't think I understand, if you make a new book every time a new book page is created, every page will only belong to that single book, leaving me not clear on what the purpose is of creating a book.

Comment: Only when a new node of content type *my-book* is created it will create a new book. This will be the top level book page. The *my-page* node will be added as child to this book.